# AddIndex_Management throws maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, indexing

The following script is run to create indexes across all the feature classes within a particular dataset:

```
import arcpy
import os.path

def listFcsInGDB():
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets("FRED.GS*", "Feature") + ['']:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('', '', fds):
            yield os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fds, fc)

def listIndexNamesInFeature(f):
    return [i.name for i in arcpy.ListIndexes(f)]

def listFieldNamesInFeature(f):
    return [i.name for i in arcpy.ListFields(f)]

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\rmorgan\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog\ds08.sde"
idx_stub = "IXGS_"
attributes = [
                "QASTATUS", "POINTUSAGE",
                #... several more here
            ]

fc = listFcsInGDB()
for f in fc:
    indexes = listIndexNamesInFeature(f)
    fieldList = listFieldNamesInFeature(f)
    for a in attributes:
        if a not in fieldList:
            print a + " is not in " + f
            continue
        if any(a[:4] in s for s in indexes):
            print a + " has an index already in " + f
            continue
        arcpy.AddIndex_management(f, a, idx_stub +  a)
        print a + " is now indexed in " + f
```

After some time of successfully creating around a hundred indexes, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PyScripts\AddIndexes.py", line 57, in <module>
    arcpy.AddIndex_management(f, a, idx_stub + str(counter) + a)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5271, in AddIndex
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Underlying DBMS error [ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded] [FRED.GS_FC1]
....
Underlying DBMS error [Error executing stored procedure sde.version_util.close_state::ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded] [SDE.DEFAULT][STATE_ID = 2561192]
Wrong column type [ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded]
Underlying DBMS error [ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded]
Underlying DBMS error
Underlying DBMS error
Underlying DBMS error
Underlying DBMS error
Underlying DBMS error
Underlying DBMS error
Failed to execute (AddIndex).
```

This is ArcMap 10.1 running on top on Oracle 11g SDE.

Running the Oracle command `show parameter open_curs;` results in 2000 cursors.  Certainly, this script doesn't need 2000 cursors.  There are about 35 feature classes and 15 fields needing indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation, the problem was the order of deploying the changes.

In a previous step, the dataset containing these feature classes was registered as versioned.  Then the above 'arcpy.AddIndex_management' was called.

If indexes are added **before** enabling versioning, all the feature classes are indexed without issue.  And much more quickly as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's no telling what actually happens behind the scenes. Maybe this thing executes one separate statement for finding the characteristics of each column of each table and forgets to close the corresponding cursors, i.e it leaks cursors.

One simple test is to increase the maximum number of cursors per session. Best is to ask your DBA do to that, since it requires DBA rights. If you are using your own Oracle playpen, then do this:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
ALTER SYSTEM SET open_cursors = 3000 SCOPE=BOTH;
```

and rerun your test.

Setting the number higher has no impact on ressource usage per se. Each open cursor does however consume resources.

I consider it a bug for a process to need so many open cursors; most likely it forgets to close cursors it opens. That must be fixed: increasing the number of cursors allowed is just a way to avoid an error being generated.